NPM Installations not complete
I tried to execute the command "npm install" on my Mac, but it threw an error as shown in the screenshot below.

Has anyone else faced the same issue and managed to resolve it?
Tried to execute the npm cache clean --force and followed by npm install but still faced same issue. I want to install the npm successfully.
